# PIL.Image.save() to an FTP server

Tags: python, ftp, python-imaging-library, file-transfer

Right now, I have the following code:

```
pilimg = PILImage.open(img_file_tmp) # img_file_tmp just contains the image to read
pilimg.thumbnail((200,200), PILImage.ANTIALIAS)
pilimg.save(fn, 'PNG') # fn is a filename
```

This works just fine for saving to a local file pointed to by `fn`. However, what I would want this to do instead is to save the file on a remote FTP server.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python's `ftplib` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) can initiate an FTP transfer, but PIL cannot write directly to an FTP server.

What you *can* do is write the result to a file and then upload it to the FTP server using the FTP library. There are complete examples of how to connect in the `ftplib` manual so I'll focus just on the sending part:

```
# (assumes you already created an instance of FTP
#  as "ftp", and already logged in)
f = open(fn, 'r')
ftp.storbinary("STOR remote_filename.png", f)
```

If you have enough memory for the compressed image data, you can avoid the intermediate file by having PIL write to a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), and then passing that object into the FTP library:

```
import StringIO
f = StringIO()
image.save(f, 'PNG')

f.seek(0) # return the StringIO's file pointer to the beginning of the file

# again this assumes you already connected and logged in
ftp.storbinary("STOR remote_filename.png", f)
```