# Python 3 - Upload PIL Binary to FTP server

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, python-imaging-library

im new to python and i try to upload a image to FTP in python 3.

I'm taking the pic with the raspberry camera modul and write it to a binary. After this i do some actions with PIL. This part works already fine. I also can store it to a JPEG file. 
I wanna skip the file storage and upload the image directly from memory. 
I found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715940/pil-image-save-to-an-ftp-server):

```
import StringIO
f = StringIO()
image.save(f, 'PNG')

f.seek(0) # return the StringIO's file pointer to the beginning of the file

# again this assumes you already connected and logged in
ftp.storbinary("STOR remote_filename.png", f)
```

Based on this i created my code (only the important lines):

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')  # take pic, streaming method
stream.seek(0) # "Rewind" the stream to the beginning so we can read its content
img_web = Image.open(stream)

size=[web_width, web_height] # some PIL editing
img_web=img_web.resize(size) # resize

session = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, ftp_user, ftp_pwd)  # ftp upload
img_web.seek(0)
temp = io.StringIO() # this is a file object
img_web.save(temp, format='JPEG') # save the content to temp
temp.seek(0)
session.storbinary('STOR /home/www/test.jpg' , temp)
```

But this does not work and i get the following error:

```
 img_web.save(temp, format='JPEG') # save the content to temp
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1685, in save
   save_handler(self, fp, filename)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 657, in _save
   fp.write(_MAGIC)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just played a bit with the code and i found the solution. It's so simple.
Instead of

```
temp = io.StringIO()
```

i only had to use:

```
temp = io.BytesIO()
```